# Calling one Django app API URL inside another app for displaying in front end using React.js

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project with Django and React.js. I get a response from an API using `django-restframework` and display the API response in the front end using React.js.

I have two Django apps, namely `users` and `leave`, which have separate API URLs.

I want to call the `leave` API URLs in the React part of my `users` app and display it in the front end.

The problem is, when I call the `leave` API URL inside the `users` app React.js part, I am not getting a proper response.

Comment: Hopefully we can add some clarity here. So you have 2 stand alone (**a** and **b**), separate single page apps? and each app connects to its own API (**a** -> **a** and **b** -> **b**). However in one circumstance you need app **a** to connect to API **b**?

Comment: yes sir @PhilHauser

Comment: Can you paste your current XHR / ajax / fetch call?

Comment: I changed and applied as your answer and its working.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to be easier to read and understand. Generally it's best to include a full code example and the error you are seeing too. Could you do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 fetch actions / methods, `fetchFromApiA` and `fetchFromApiB`. Or you can put the api hosts in a config and pass an options to your `fetch` action.

So `{"API_ROOT_A": "http://url-for-a.com", "API_ROOT_B": "http://url-for-b.com"}`

Then, crudely, in your fetch you could do:

```
let url = hostA ? config.API_ROOT_A : config.API_ROOT_B;
```